# How to set the initial value of useState with the value of another state set in a useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

1. I get user data from Firestore in a `useEffect` hook and then put the data in a state. This part works fine.

```
const [profile, setProfile] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
// Get user profile data from firestore.. 
    setProfile(userData) 
}, [])
```

2. I have HTML radio inputs where user can change their gender but I need to set the initial gender (one they choose during sign-up) with a state.

```
const defaultGender = profile.gender
const [gender, setGender] = useState(defaultGender)

<input onChange={e => setGender(e.target.value)} type="radio" id="Man" name="gender" value="Man" checked={defaultGender === "Man"} /> <label htmlFor="Man">Man</label>

<input onChange={e => setGender(e.target.value)} type="radio" id="Woman" name="gender" value="Woman" checked={defaultGender === "Woman"} /> 
<label htmlFor="Woman">Woman</label>
```

The problem is, with this code, `console.log(gender)` returns `undefined` and I can not check (select) a different gender as it is stuck on Man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just need to:

1. Use `gender` from the state (not `defaultGender`) for the `checked` input's prop.
2. Update your `gender` state after the `profile` state updating.

[CodePen](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-resonance-xzps7?file=/src/index.js)

```js
const { useState, useEffect, Fragment } = React;

const Form = () => {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});
  const [gender, setGender] = useState(profile.gender);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Assuming you have an async request here...
    const profile = { gender: "Woman" };
    setProfile(profile);
    setGender(profile.gender);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <input
        onChange={(e) => setGender(e.target.value)}
        type="radio"
        id="Man"
        name="gender"
        value="Man"
        checked={gender === "Man"}
      />
      <label htmlFor="Man">Man</label>
      <input
        onChange={(e) => setGender(e.target.value)}
        type="radio"
        id="Woman"
        name="gender"
        value="Woman"
        checked={gender === "Woman"}
      />
      <label htmlFor="Woman">Woman</label>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.body);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this `const [details, setDetails] = useState({});
 const [expyear, setExpyear] = useState( Object.keys(details.Details.Expense[0])[0]);` and it shows `Expense undefined`, any solution ?

Comment: @ShubhamSinghvi you should create another question post with more details.

Comment: yeah i did that, can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72417149/set-initial-state-value-from-object-value-of-another-state) out