# Set initial state value from object value of another state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const Home = () => {
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({});
  const [expyear, setExpyear] = useState(Object.keys(details.Details.Expense[0])[0]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    // data fetched from api ...
    const details = res.data[0];
    setDetails(details);
    setExpyear(Object.keys(details.Details.Expense[0])[0]);
  }, []);
};
```

I am trying to set state value from another state value after referring from [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045118/how-to-set-the-initial-value-of-usestate-with-the-value-of-another-state-set-in) but this didn't solved my problem. Any solution why this is not working ?

[image]
This is how my data appears

Comment: Tips 1: Pass dependency array in use effect `useEffect(()=> ......,[details])`,    Tips 2:state changes doesnot effect next line instantly,  You can use async/await, ...   Tips 3: `setExpyear(Object.keys(res.data?.[0].Details.Expense[0])[0])`  , follow any one

Comment: I am getting the error while initializing the state value as `Expense is undefined` which here is line:3, can you demonstrate a solution for that

Comment: Add your real data, please.

Comment: console.log your value and check, what is structure of your object, may be you pointing wrong key

Comment: in line 3, keep blank usestate, `useState()`

Comment: @RiTeSh I've edited the question adding the structure of my data, and i also have logged the same resulting the expected output

Comment: can you share which variable you doing console, its res.data[0] or details,

Comment: and you getting error in Line 3 or inside useEffect ?

Comment: This is a bad idea. Derived state shuld not be a separate state.

Comment: @ShubhamSinghvi add the real JSON, please, not an image.

Comment: @RiTeSh I was getting error while initializing the state, but as you told I removed the value and kept it as blank, and it was working fine